# Why can't I boot?

Tags: dual-boot

I get this when I try to boot after installing from CD:

```
GNU GRUB version 1.99-21ubuntu 3.14  

Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible
command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions.

grub>
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you installed GRUB in the wrong location.

You need to have the GRUB boot code in the MBR, which you must have, since it gets loaded.  But this needs to point to a valid partition containing the rest of the GRUB code, including the menu.  Either it's pointing to the wrong place, or something changed.

It can be fixed easily, either with Super Grub Disk, the [Boot Repair Disk](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files) or the Ubuntu live CD.

I'm sure you can find a number of tutorials, many of them on askubuntu.com.

Comment: I get this problem with my live USB stick. How can this happen? (See http://askubuntu.com/questions/465385/ubuntu-all-of-a-sudden-fails-to-boot-on-thinkpad-t430)

Comment: Your problem is definitely different than what I described here, since the CD or USB won't work.

Comment: Oh, you are the same guy. Shame on me, sorry.